# Trying to create postgis inside docker file gives the error

Tags: postgresql, docker

Here is the command that I'm trying to run.

I'm using official postgres docker image.
I can't find any info about 'is not a database cluster directory'

```
Step 7 : RUN pg_ctl start -w &&     createdb postgis_template -E UTF8 &&    psql -d postgis_template -c "create extension if not exists postgis;" &&    pg_ctl stop -w
     ---> Running in da5745cab398
    pg_ctl: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" is not a database cluster directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting this error because there is no database cluster created inside the postgres docker image when you're attempting to run the `pg_ctl start` command.

The database cluster is created when you run a docker container based on the image, as the `initdb` binary is called as part of the `docker-entrypoint.sh` script that is set as the `ENTRYPOINT` for the postgres container.

- See https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/cb70a79c1a8248d7e0db89d79dfbd08dd481be7f/9.4/Dockerfile#L47 for the line that sets the script as the `ENTRYPOINT`
- See https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/cb70a79c1a8248d7e0db89d79dfbd08dd481be7f/9.4/docker-entrypoint.sh#L11 for the line that calls `initdb`.

If you're running your postgres container with a mounted data volume that is persistent across container restarts, you can just run this command once from a psql shell,  or you can override the `docker-entrypoint.sh` script and add your own custom one that creates the postgis extension.

Comment: And if I dont? I wan't to have complete working db with extensions after docker run

Comment: You can try and run initdb yourself in your Dockerfile - I can't see any reason why that wouldn't work.